# c++ Iterative push_back via concatenation?

Tags: c++, sfml

This is my first time asking on stackoverflow, so please let me know if anything isn't right in my question. So I have code as follows:

```
sf::IntRect WALK_UP0(80, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP1(144, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP2(208, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP3(272, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP4(336, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP5(400, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP6(464, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP7(528, 526, 32, 48);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP0);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP1);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP2);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP3);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP4);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP5);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP6);
WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP7);
```

I'm wondering if there's some way I can iterate through these push_back statements (I'm assuming initialization can't be done via iteration). Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UP + i)
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, C++ preprocessor  does  not support loops. Can  you show where you define and initialize the `WALK_UP0..7`?

Comment: You might consider developing a more data driven approach rather than hardcoding values in code. Much faster iteration time and you can change things without needing to recompile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid declaring a variable for every entry of your vector, you can do it several ways:

- Insert the elements using a temporary IntRect

  ```
  WALK_UP.push_back(IntRect{100, 100, 200, 200});
  // or if you are lazy, just write
  WALK_UP.push_back({100, 100, 200, 200});
  ```

  This is basically the same since the only possible argument type is some kind of IntRect
  (more specifically `const IntRect&` (lvalue) or `IntRect&&` (rvalue), but you mostly don't need to know the difference)
- Directly construct the elements in the vector

  ```
  WALK_UP.emplace_back(100, 100, 200, 200);
  ```

  In this case, the arguments of `emplace_back` get forwarded to the IntRect constructor.
- Insert many elements at the same time

  ```
  WALK_UP.insert(WALK_UP.end(), {
      IntRect{100, 100, 200, 200},
      // or again shorter:
      {100, 100, 200, 200},
      ...
      {123, 456, 789, 123}
  });
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Use an array, eg:

```
sf::IntRect WALK_UPs[8] = {
    sf::IntRect(80, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(144, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(208, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(272, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(336, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(400, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(464, 526, 32, 48),
    sf::IntRect(528, 526, 32, 48)
};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    WALK_UP.push_back(WALK_UPs[i]);
}
```

In which case, you *can* initialize using iterators, if these are the only elements being pushed into the container (I'm assuming you are using `std::vector`):

```
WALK_UP = std::vector<sf::IntRect>(WALK_UPs, WALK_UPs+8);
```

Or, if you still need the individual variables (eg, if they are being used for other purposes), you can use an array of pointers:

```
sf::IntRect WALK_UP0(80, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP1(144, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP2(208, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP3(272, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP4(336, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP5(400, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP6(464, 526, 32, 48);
sf::IntRect WALK_UP7(528, 526, 32, 48);

sf::IntRect* WALK_UPs[8] = {
    &WALK_UP0,
    &WALK_UP1,
    &WALK_UP2,
    &WALK_UP3,
    &WALK_UP4,
    &WALK_UP5,
    &WALK_UP6,
    &WALK_UP7,
};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    WALK_UP.push_back(*(WALK_UPs[i]));
};
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to duplicate the current contents of WALK_UP at the end of WALK_UP you could do the following. Note that some ways that might occur to someone (such as using std::copy with std::back_inserter) may not be safe depending on the type of WALK_UP due to iterator invalidation.

```
for(size_t ndx = 0, count = WALK_UP.size(); count>ndx; ++ndx)
  WALK_UP.push_back(&WALK_UP[ndx]);
```